# How to select default subnet if particular subnet is not available in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**A** - Default public subnet (always available)

 **B** - Private subnet

I want to create EC2 instance on particular subnet depends upon the availability on AWS.

As described above the public subnet "A" is always available and private subnet "B" is not available always. While selecting subnet it should find and select the private subnet "B" if it is available, if not choose public subnet "A".

How can i achieve this with Terraform?

Comment: What do you mean by not available? Can you create a [mcve] that explains more clearly what you mean and what you've tried?

Comment: If subnet B is not available, would you not instead want to create it? Specifically a machine configured for a private subnet is going to be different than a machine configured for a public subnet. If is not a good practice to use the default public subnet, instead defining your own VPC and networking as part of your project.

Answer (score 0):

In typical Terraform usage, we model that sort of distinction not by checking whether something exists and reacting to it but instead by *declaring* whether it ought to exist or not in a particular situation and failing if that statement is false.

This is illustrated in the Terraform guide [Module Composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html), which shows how we can write a module that requires an AWS VPC without that module needing to know how that VPC was created. In particular, see [Conditional Creation of Objects](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html#conditional-creation-of-objects), which shows a situation similar to what you are describing, but with an AWS AMI instead of a subnet.

Adapting that to your situation, it would be a module that expects to be given an AWS subnet, but doesn't know how that subnet was created or decided. Then you'd write a separate calling configuration for each of your environments, deciding in each one whether it will require a "private subnet" to be available or whether it'll just use the default subnet.

A separate configuration for each environment is the best way to model the inevitable differences between environments because it allows you to write down the exact shape you expect for each environment and thus makes the configuration serve also as documentation for your expectations. You can then use shared modules to factor out what the different environments have in common, potentially connecting those shared modules differently where the architecture between the environments differs.